# flutter version compatibility with m1 chip

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

I want to replace my old laptop with macbook m1, but does m1 support flutter version 2 (2.06) for development process

that's because the office doesn't want to upgrade the flutter version to the latest version

Is there anyone here who can confirm it runs or not?

Comment: specifically version 2 (2.06) or the latest? as you must sooner migrate to 3 else you would be locked-out in a older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use M1 chip almost 2 years. No issue so far with flutter v2. It works well with flutter version 1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you read [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Developing-with-Flutter-on-Apple-Silicon), you can see that:

> "We recommend using Flutter 2.5 or later on Apple Silicon machines.
> You must also have the Rosetta 2 translation environment available..."